# Import file dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-365

it is possible to download dynamics CRM import File ? if Yes please let me know how.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No You cannot download Import file.

You should have it with you the imported file.

but you could check the import record with it's log and it can give you more information which fields were mapped, it will not be completed unless you have an error in your import job.

Easier way is go to any of the view for ex.Contact and then export excel file with given fields and use the same file as csv/excel and import it.

[Here is nice article explaining the details](https://carldesouza.com/updating-dynamics-365-records-using-export-and-import-with-excel/)